# Using terraform module output as input for terraform provider parameter

Tags: terraform

At VMware we are building a terraform provider for NSXT
The format is:

```
provider "nsxt" {
  host             = "${var.host}"
  vmc_token        = "${var.vmc_token}"
}
```

What I want to do is using the output of a module (running with another provider) as input for this provider like

```
provider "nsxt" {
  host             = "${module.SDDC.proxy}"
  vmc_token        = "${var.vmc_token}"
}
```

I am not sure it’s possible.
When I run terraform plan I immediately get an error:
`Error: host must be provided`
 
Any idea on that?

Comment: What's `module.SDDC`?

Comment: This is definitely possible in the generic sense and is used in cases like creating an EKS cluster and then connecting to it with the Kubernetes provider or creating an RDS instance and then connecting to it with the Postgresql provider. Can you provide a way to reproduce your error in a [mcve]?

Comment: Unfortunately, i needed to apply 2 stages to get that working. phase1 will compute the needed parameter and phase2 will import it.

Answer (score 0):

Your module SDDC should contain `output` values, like:

```
output "proxy" {
  value = "Some value"
}
// or something like this:
output "proxy_ip" {
  value = azurerm_public_ip.test.ip_address
}
```